# bash - how to put $RANDOM into value?

Tags: bash

newbie to bash:

basically I want to compare the result of $RANDOM to another value which is given by the user through 'read'

code for more info:

```
echo $RANDOM % 10 + 1 | bc
```

basically I want an if statement as well to see if the result of that $RANDOM value is equal to something that the user typed in e.g.:

```
if [ [$RANDOM VALUE] is same as $readinput
#readinput is the thing that was typed before
then
echo "well done you guessed it"
fi
```

something along the lines of that!!

to summarise

how do i make it so that i can compare a read input value to `echo "$RANDOM % 10 + 1 | bc"`

think of the program I am making as 'GUESS THE NUMBER!'

all help VERY MUCH APPRECIATED :)

Comment: Expanding `$RANDOM` is actually performed by bash itself, `bc` isn't involved in the random-number-generation part *at all* -- the only thing it does in your code is a modulo and an addition, but you don't *need* it for either of those things.

Comment: By the way -- I'm inclined to argue that you really should be breaking this question down further into components before asking it. For instance: If you were asking how to store the output of an arbitrary command in a variable, then it wouldn't need to have anything to do with `bc` or `RANDOM`. If you were asking how to compare two variables, likewise. This question really has several different operations built into it as assumptions, but it's not clear that any of those are the Right Thing For The Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `bc` here -- since you're dealing in integers, native math will do.

```
printf 'Guess a number: '; read readinput

target=$(( (RANDOM % 10) + 1 )) ## or, less efficiently, target=$(bc <<<"$RANDOM % 10 + 1")

if [ "$readinput" = "$target" ]; then
  echo "You correctly guessed $target"
else
  echo "Sorry -- you guessed $readinput, but the real value is $target"
fi
```

---

The important thing, though, is the `test` command -- also named `[`.

```
test "$readinput" = "$target"
```

...is exactly the same as...

```
[ "$readinput" = "$target" ]
```

...which does the work of comparing two values and exiting with an exit status of 0 (which `if` will treat as true) should they match, or a nonzero exit status (which `if` will treat as false) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use command substitution to store your randomly generated value, then ask the user for a guess, then compare the two. Here's a very simple example:

```
#/bin/bash

#Store the random number for comparison later using command substitution IE: $(command) or `command`
random=$(echo "$RANDOM % 10 + 1" | bc)

#Ask the user for their guess and store in variable user_guess
read -r -p "Enter your guess: " user_guess

#Compare the two numbers
if [ "$random" -eq "$user_guess" ]; then
    echo "well done you guessed it"
else
    echo "sorry, try again"
fi
```

Perhaps a more robust guessing program would be embedded in a loop so that it would keep asking the user until they got the correct answer. Also you should probably check that the user entered a whole number.

```
#!/bin/bash

keep_guessing=1

while [ "$keep_guessing" -eq 1 ]; do

    #Ask the user for their guess and check that it is a whole number, if not start the loop over.
    read -r -p "Enter your guess: " user_guess
    [[ ! $user_guess =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && { echo "Please enter a number"; continue; }

    #Store the random number for comparison later
    random=$(echo "$RANDOM % 10 + 1" | bc)

    #Compare the two numbers
    if [ "$random" -eq "$user_guess" ]; then
            echo "well done you guessed it"
            keep_guessing=0
    else
            echo "sorry, try again"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Yes adding quotes around the variables in my test would prevent shell globbing etc... but they aren't necessary in this case. The way RANDOM is being used here it will always be a number less than 10 and it will not have spaces in it. Also the user_guess variable's value is being scrubbed to ensure it is a number with no spaces in it. This should run as is no problem.

Comment: If IFS doesn't have any numbers in it, that is. If `IFS=0`, `109` could become two words, `1` and `9`. More importantly -- leaving the quotes out means there's more logic and context that needs to be evaluated to determine correctness, and without comments to the effect, what goes into that evaluation isn't visible to a reader. Showing best practices through our examples even when they don't matter means the folks we're teaching are more likely to follow them when they do.

Comment: Added the rest of the missing quotes; changed `foo && echo && continue` to `foo && { echo; continue; }` so that we always `continue` if `foo` succeeds even if `echo` fails; added the missing `-r` argument to `read` to suppress backslash-mangling (if the user enters `1\9` we want to reject that with "please enter a number", not treat it as `19`). I think this is sound now.